# Reimplementation of svg line not functioning

Tags: javascript, svg, line

I've drawn a line before with this exact code but when reimplementing it into another project something isn't working.

```
let main = document.getElementById('main');
let svg = document.createElement('svg');
let newLine = document.createElement('line');
svg.setAttribute('style', `position: fixed;display: block;`);

newLine.setAttribute('x1', 0);
newLine.setAttribute('y1', 0);
newLine.setAttribute('x2', 500);
newLine.setAttribute('y2', 500);
newLine.setAttribute('style', `stroke:red;stroke-width:100;`);
svg.appendChild(newLine);
main.appendChild(svg);
```

Before I was running an express server and JSDOM to fill a div in the document with svg's then sending the innerhtml of the document element as the body when routing to '/', not the most performant way to do it but I was just playing around around with tools we were learning in class. When I put the code below into my html a black line is displayed as it should so I feel I'm missing some small piece...

```
<svg width="500" height="500"> 
 <line x1="50" y1="50" x2="350" y2="350" stroke="black" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `createElementNS` when creating your `svg` and `line` elements, otherwise it just thinks they're made up tags and not actual SVG.

Also, since you're not using variables in your `setAttribute`, you should avoid string interpolation and just use single-quotes instead of backticks.

#### Solution

```js
let main = document.getElementById('main');
let svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
let newLine = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','line');
svg.setAttribute('style', 'position: fixed;display: block;');

newLine.setAttribute('x1', 0);
newLine.setAttribute('y1', 80);
newLine.setAttribute('x2', 100);
newLine.setAttribute('y2', 20);
newLine.setAttribute('style', 'stroke:red;stroke-width:100;');
svg.appendChild(newLine);
main.appendChild(svg);
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

#### Documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, needed to use the code below when declaring my svg

```
const svgTop = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg')
```